# Как сделать копию проекта, который задействует локальный сервер, в PhpStorm

Tags: php, mysql, phpstorm, jetbrains

Я пишу проект в php storm, и немного опасаюсь, что внесенные мною изменения в проект могут его однажды сильно подпортить, поэтому интересно, возможно ли сделать копию рабочей версии проекта, для того, чтобы в случае какой либо большой неудачи при работе с проектом вернуться к этой копии? Использую связку PhpStorm + OpenServer(mySQL). Соответственно, работаю с базами данных, который обновляются на локальном сервер. Спасибо!

Comment: папку с проектом  ctrl+с ctrl+v ?))) А вообще можно использовать SVN, Git, Mercurial и тогда копии не нужны

Comment: Дело в том, что если использовать ctrl + c, ctrl + v, то нельзя будет откатится до прежней версии проекта в изменениях, внесенных в базу данных, которая находится на локальном сервере.

Comment: То есть базы данных на локальном сервере не будут изменены. Если ctrl с ctrl v использовать

Comment: для БД придётся делать бэкап. А вообще, можно либо сделать, либо поискать на гитхабе и прикрутить к проекту такую штуку, как миграции. Которые позволят и накатывать изменения в БД и откатывать до нужной. И вот git+миграции - было бы самое оно. А пока только dump БД и backup проекта в ручном режиме

Comment: Я забыл упомянуть, что я использую laravel, и миграции в проекте как раз присутствуют. Как они могут помочь ?